# Nginx forwarding git.example.com to www.example.com

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04, gitlab

As in the title, my website, git.mad3ngineer.net forwards to www.mad3ngineer.net. However, my ci.mad3ngineer.net uses the same system but works just fine...

The website can be checked out at http://git.mad3ngineer.net which you can see forwards you to the default site, which is currently just a drab html document made in vi. However, if you type in http://ci.mad3ngineer.net it magically works!!! And, not to mention... If you add the /users/sign_in to git.mad3ngineer.net... Like so: git.mad3ngineer.net/users/sign_in it magically works as well :O... How can this be? What am I doing wrong? I have rebooted the server, reloaded the configs, and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Here is my nginx site-configuration file:

```
upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

upstream gitlabci {
  server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-ci/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server{
    listen      80 default_server;
    server_name 192.168.1.10 mad3ngineer.net www.mad3ngineer.net;

    root /var/www/mad3ngineer.net;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /gitlab {
        rewrite ^/gitlab/(.*) http://git.mad3ngineer.net$1 break;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

    }
}

server{
        listen 80;
        server_name ci.mad3ngineer.net;
        server_tokens off;

        root /var/opt/gitlab/git-data;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        client_max_body_size 20m;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlabci;
        }

        location @gitlabci {
                proxy_read_timeout 300;
                proxy_connect_timeout 300; # Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
                proxy_redirect     off;

                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Frame-Options   SAMEORIGIN;

                proxy_pass http://gitlabci;
        }
}

server{
        listen 80;
        server_name git.mad3ngineer.net gitlab.mad3ngineer.net;
        server_tokens off;

        root /var/opt/gitlab/git-data;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        client_max_body_size 20m;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
        }

        location @gitlab {
                proxy_read_timeout 300;
                proxy_connect_timeout 300; # Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
                proxy_redirect     off;

                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Frame-Options   SAMEORIGIN;

                proxy_pass http://gitlab;
        }
}
```

SOLVED: 
I had to change the root value to /var/opt/gitlab/nginx for git.mad3ngineer.net. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure "root" directory of both servers to proper paths.

both root set as below:

```
 root /var/opt/gitlab/git-data;
```

your gitlab directory may contain a redirection based on your its production/development config yaml file look for "gitlab_url".